# Unable to configure Kony Studio with iOS sdk

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am following [this](http://docs.kony.com/konyLibrary/studio/studio_installation_guide_mac/Default.htm#running_sample_app.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____11) tutorial to configure iOS sdk with Kony Studio. But I got following error :-

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1904)
    at com.pat.tool.keditor.utils.IOSBuildUtils.getSdkAndSimulatorTypesForXcode6(IOSBuildUtils.java:249)
    at com.pat.tool.keditor.preferences.IOSPreferencePage$CustomSelectionAdapter$3.run(IOSPreferencePage.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

[image]

Comment: Kony Studio 7 is out. All works fine there :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen if you refresh the Base SDK Version in your Preferences -> Kony Dev Studio -> iOS in version 6.5.2 (confirmed on GA_v201509231311_r1). Probably a bug.

I got around it by:

[image: iOS Preferences]

1. Restoring Defaults
2. Refreshing the xCode Version (7.2 pops up)
3. Applying the settings
4. Exit Preferences
5. **Then close and restart Kony Studio** and the settings magically appear by themselves

[image]

Make sure you've got xCode installed properly and if you have multiple versions of xCode running maybe try with only one first.

Comment: This Solution + Making sure that Xcode is placed in the correct folder, solved the problem for me.